# R appends 'NA' when slicing vector

Tags: r, slice

I use R to try to make a slice of `sc` and put it into `sci`. However, for some reason R appends 'NA' to `sci`. Why? What is happening, what am I doing wrong? In Python I *do* get the correct result.

```
> sc
 [1] 12646      1295       131        20         0         0         1
> i
[1] 1
> sc[1+i:length(sc)]
 [1] 1295      131       20        0        0        1       NA
> length(sc)
[1] 7
> length(sci)
[1] 7
```

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan It is OK to post question and the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: What is happening is that you are referring to vector `sc` element `1 + length(sc)` (forget the `i`). That element doesn't exist so R extends the vector with a `NA` value.

Answer (score -1):

R uses vector/array slicing syntax to Python (using the `start:stop` notation), however the underlying machinery is **completely different** from that of Python.
In Python, this notation is truly purely a slicing syntax, and has no meaning outside two `[]` brackets for indexing an iterable:

```
>>> 1:5
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You'll also notice that anything before the colon `:` is considered part of `start` (and anything after the colon is part of `stop`):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> i = 1
>>> a[1+i:len(a)]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Not that Python uses zero-based indexing.

However in R, `start:stop` does have its own meaning even outside slicing and is regarded as its own entity, on which you can perform arithmetic:

```
1:5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
1+1:5
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
1+1:5/2
[1] 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5
```

So this answers the question of what is happening. When you type `1+i:length(sc)`, `1` is added to every element in `i:length(sc)`.
Instead, writing `(1+i):length(sc)` (using brackets to define `start`) will produce the result you desire.

Comment: This issue and "answer" pertains to *basic* [R operator syntax & precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) (see also the relevant section from the official [R Language Definition on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Infix-and-prefix-operators)). I don't think this warrants an independent answer.

Comment: I have problems with the first sentence: "R uses vector/array slicing syntax ... using the start:stop notation". This isn't technically true, since there is not a "slicing" concept in R. When you subset, you tell the indices of the original vector you want to keep. The `start:stop` notation just creates a vector which, in turn, can be used in subsetting.